# Is there a way to transfer data from my FTP server to Azure storage?

Tags: ftp, azure

I am trying to copy/move data that is on my FTP server to an Azure storage account/container. I have over 2TB of data, so there's no way I could download it all and just upload it to Azure. Is there a way to do it through a client such as Filezilla? Or is there something in Azure that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is one of the following applications:

- [Azure Storage Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) - GUI based Azure Blob storage management
- [AZCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) - Command line data transfer tool for Azure storage
- [Azure Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) - Mount Azure storage as a local file system

I realize this may not get you exactly what you're asking. But, these are the official tools Microsoft has provided. You may have to bridge the gap between your FTP server and file system, depending on your specific scenario.

For instance, it depends on if you can login to the FTP server directly. If you can somehow mount the storage on a Windows server temporarily, etc. There isn't enough details to tell you how to bridge that gap in the best way. Ultimately, you may have no choice but to use your computer as a go between, by downloading and then uploading the data in some fashion.

As an idea, you could setup a temporary Windows Server in Azure, use Azure Files to mount your blob storage and then use an FTP client running on the Windows server to fetch the FTP data and send it to the file share. This would free your system and bandwidth from having to perform the task and would likely be much faster.

Finally, if you are interested in doing a drive shipment, instead of transferring data over the internet. You have that option as well: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage-import-export/

Comment: Ahh, okay. For clarification, I log directly into the server from Filezilla, so I guess I'll have to set up a bridge. I tried creating a logic app to do it (I know you can move files as they are added) but i couldn't get that to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @andrewbuikema Yes, the only way to avoid being in the middle, to the best of my knowledge, would be to use the tools provided on a cloud hosted server temporarily.  In that way, the cloud server is the "bridge."